# string initialization in C

Tags: c, string, insertion-sort

I am writing insertion sort using strings. I have char arrays like:

```
 char array1[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
 char array2[4] = {'b', 'd', 'e', '\0'};
```

And I need to use this operation:

```
char string[2];
string[1] = array1;
string[2] = array2;
```

Is it possible ?

Because in insertion sort I need a string.
This is the insertion code:

```
char* insertionsort(char* a, int n) {
   int k;
   for (k = 1; k < n; ++k) {
      int key = a[k];
      int i = k - 1;

      while ((i >= 0) && (key < a[i])) {
         a[i + 1] = a[i];
         --i;
      }

      a[i + 1] = key;
   }

   return a;
}
```

Comment: Your arrays are too  small -- there's no space for the null terminator. Use `array1[]` instead to have them automatically sized.

Comment: Your arrays should have size `4`, not `3`. And `char string [2];` was supposed to be `char *string [2];` I guess.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate those two arrays ? or do you want to make an array of arrays ?

Comment: My goal is creating string array. In insertion sort I need string array.So I want to make an array of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I need to write this operation :

```
char string [2];
string[1] = array1;
string[2] = array2;
```

> Is it possible ?

Short answer: no, it's not. Arrays are not assignable. You can use `strcpy` to copy the elements from one string to another, but in this case that won't work either -- you've defined `string` as an array of 2 chars, but you're trying to assign an entire array of chars to each of those.

It's not entirely clear that it's what you want, but one possibility would be:

```
char *string[2];
string[1] = array1;
string[2] = array2;
```

In this case, `string` is an array of two *pointers* to char, and the assignments set those to point to the first character of each of your previously defined strings.

Since you've tagged this as both C and C++, I'll add a bit about that: this is written as very much C code. If you're actually using C++, you probably want something more like:

```
std::string[2] = {"abc", "bde"};
```

Even in C, I'd prefer to initialize and use string constants where they make sense:

```
char array1[] = "abc";
char array2[] = "bde";

char *string[] = {array1, array2};
```

Or even just:

```
 char const *string[] = {"abc", "bde"};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char array1[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};  // same as char *array1 = "abc";
char array2[4] = {'b', 'd', 'e', '\0'};  // same as char *array2 = "bde";

char *string [2]; // an array of 'pointers to chars' / array of strings

string[1] = array1; // this will work
string[2] = array2; // this will work
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I guess I need to figure out how to make things look like code.  My apologies for casusing inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Just remember,

```
    char ary[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}; //define an array of char
```

When you use ary like this:

```
    char string[2];
    string[0] = ary;
```

ary degenerates from the name of an array to a pointer! So, what you do above is assigning a pointer to a char type, and which will lead to a type warning when compiling.

This is very important in C!

And you can fix it like this:

```
    char *string[2];             //an array of pointers to char
    string[1] = array1;          //correct
    string[2] = array2;
```